# Why we should always return values from a function?

Tags: php, function, return

I am not a big programming guy but have listen from programmers a lot of times that we should always return values from a function. I want to know the reason.

Comment: RTFM : http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: @diEcho - That link to the manual doesn't really answer this question at all...

Comment: This is pretty subjective and probably a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ — don't be surprised if people vote to close it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function needn't return anything... If you look at C(++) function, many of them don't (well, not explicitly):

```
void nonReturningFunction(const int *someParam);
int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    nonReturningFunction(&i);
    return 0;
}
void nonReturningFunction(const int *someParam)
{
    printf("I print the value of a parameter: %d",someParam);
}
```

The latter returns nothing, well, it returns a void. The main function does return something: `0`, this is generally a signal to the system to let it know the programme is finished, and it finished well.

The same logic applies to PHP, or any other programming language. Some functions' return value is relevant, another function may not be required to return anything. In general functions return values because they are relevant to the flow of your programme.

Take a class, for example:

```
<?php
    class Foo
    {
        private $foo,$bar;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->foo = 'bar';
        }
        public function getFoo()
        {
            return $this->foo;//<-- getter for private variable
        }
        public function getBar()
        {
            return $this->foo;//<-- getter for private variable
        }
        public function setBar($val = null)
        {
            $this->bar = $val;
            return $this;//<-- return instance for fluent interfacing
        }
        public function setFoo($val = null)
        {
            $this->foo = $val;
            return $this;
        }
    }
    $f = new Foo();
    $f->setFoo('foo')->setBar('bar');//<-- fluent interface
    echo $f->getFoo();
?>
```

If the setter function didn't return anything, you'd have to write:

```
$f->setFoo('foo');
$f->setBar('Bar');
```

So in this case, return values are relevant. Another example where they're irrelevant:

```
function manipulateArray(array &$arr)//<-- pass by reference
{
    sort($arr);
}
$arr = range('Z','A');
manipulateArray($arr);
var_dump($arr);//array is sorted
```

as opposed to:

```
function manipulateArray(array $arr)//<-- pass by copy
{
    sort($arr);
    return $arr;
}
$arr = range('Z','A');
manipulateArray($arr);
var_dump($arr);//array is not sorted!
$arr = manipulateArray($arr);//<-- requires reassign
```

Passing by reference is deemed risky in many cases, that's why the latter approach is generally considered to be better. So in many cases the functions needn't return a value, but they do all the same because it makes the code safer overall. 
That might be why you're under the impression that functions must *always* return a value.

Answer (score 7):

This is the heritage of old programming. In older languages like Fortran you always had to return with something with a type i.e. int, float, bool etc. Since C you can return with a "void" type, and that's the default in most C functions if you don't specify a return statement, it returns with void at the end. In Java for example you have to specify a return type and then return with that type. If you don't want to return anything, you use the 'void' type:

```
//This works
public void boo() {
   return;
}


//This gets you an error
public int boo() {
   return;
}

//This gets you an error too, because you must specify a type for any function in Java
public boo() {
   return;
}
```

So it's more like what Lix said, if you have something to return with, you do. In most functional programs your functions can return either with data, or true/false marking success or failure. In many systems a function can return an int indicating success or failure like '1' or '-1'. Unix shell programs use this.

In other languages like PHP you don't need to return anything, but in the background PHP still attaches a 'void' type as returned value to your function, you just don't have to explicitly write it.

Hope this helps

Comment: That would explain all the return 0 instead of void I've been seeing lately.

Answer (score 6):

This is done so that there is a definitive ending point for the function.  It is mainly to increase readability and to help future programmers to understand what you were trying to do.

There should be no assumption about what a function returns.

Answer (score 6):

There is so many reasons...

That's better for your architecture : a function takes parameters, work with them and returns expected result. In such way you may be able to reuse it and to arrange your code.

That's better for [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), you can very easily check if your function return expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking in computer programming a function is a reusable unit of code that takes some input (including nothing)  and returns a value.

Some languages have similar constructs to functions called procedures and these are reusable pieces of code that take some input (including nothing) and perform some activity but don't return a result.

However some languages may not have the latter as a syntactical construct and mey use functions to implement procedures. So you here you get functions where you ignore the result. Also some languages may not have an requirement to actually force the code to return something from a function (i.e. they implement procedures using functions).

So if you have only the latter as your option, then you could argue like @lix that it's good practise to return things from function. The primary reason is that though the function can be used like a procedure - the caller may call it like function and expect to work with the result. Remember that test code is a primary use case and it might be the only reason for following this convention.

Personally I think convention is the answer. Do whatever works best for you, but try to always do the same, and if you need to diverge - find ways to let the user know.

Answer (score 3):

Some earlier languages had procedures and functions. Procedures returned nothing (they just did something). Functions returned something. I guess someone decided it was unnecessary to have both since a function could simply be void (as used in C). I just wrote a quick function to store data in the database. Since the data was filtered in several levels the odds of an error was negligible, nonetheless, I included in the function an alert, that would echo on an error, so returning even an error alert wasn't necessary. (This is an in-house site, that wouldn't be for public use) so having the function return anything was completely unnecessary.

Since the question was why we should ALWAYs return a value, it's not about why it's sometimes good to return a value, but what reason exists to demand we should always return a value, and there is no valid reason to ALWAYs return a value from a function.

Answer (score 2):

Also: flexibility. Consider `echo`ing vs `return`ing from inside a function. With, say, a returned `true` or `false` from a function, you can modify how things are displayed in views in as many ways as you want. Having a string echoed doesn't give you this flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I it always depend on the particular case. For example, a static method ,should always return something, as they cannot modify object; but you can do it anyway if you pass to the method a reference to an object; like a reference variable (like pointers on C++), or simply an object (that is passed as implicit reference like in PHP). The later practice it is not a good one as if you a method that receive a reference and modify the same class where the method is defined, why not to make the method non-static?. The later will not always true if you want to have a method that is reused by various classes (maybe derived classes or abstract ones). Also nowadays for an IDE will be better declare type of variables return, so the interpreter or compiler will catch lot of errors on compilation time not running time. I think, most of the language doesnt impose a criteria for your question simple for flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Same question came to my mind while writing a function which is logging to database. I do not need to return anything. I noticed when the logging function is being called it was returning null. After some investigation I found, in case of PHP if a function does not have return, by default it returns null. I also found this in php documentation:

[PHP Documentation on function default value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

So I thought - in place of returning null, I should return some useful message, then I returned a string saying "Error Logged Successfully"