# php passing a variabile that is not always set in a user function

Tags: php, function, isset

i have created a simple function in php, but i'm not sure about how to pass a (optional) variabile if this is not always set, for example:

```
myfunction( $var1, $var2, $_POST[example] );
```

as you can see the myfunction is always called but the $_POST[example] isset/exist only when the form was already sent.

my question is, is that correct??? if $_POST[example] don't exist i see no error/notice (Notice: Undefined variable..) but i'm not sure...

maybe is better like this?

```
 myfunction( $var1, $var2, isset($_POST[example]) );
```

Comment: During function definition set the argument as optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AlmaDoMundo's answer shows: make the argument optional:

```
function myFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = null)
{
}
```

Then, to avoid warnings (undefined index), you'll have to call the function like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['example']))
{
    myFunction($var1, $var2, $_POST['example']);
}
else
{
    myFunction($var1, $var2);
}
```

If, for some reason you're unable to change the function definition (and therefore, it's signature), just call the function like this:

```
$var3 = isset($_POST['example']) ? $_POST['example'] : null;
myFunction($var1, $var2, $var3);//null is a value, so you're passing 3 arguments
```

Calling the your function the second way `myFunction($var1, $var2, isset($_POST['example']));` is *not the way forward*. Just look at `isset`'s signature

```
bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )
```

it returns a `bool` (true/false), not the value of the variable itself. If the key exists, your function will receive `true` as a third argument, if not `false`. You want to pass the actual value, so you'll have to either wrap your code in `if/else` branches, or use a ternary (`myFunction($var1, $var2, isset($_POST['example']) ? $_POST['example'] : null);`. 
Personally, I'd not use a ternary here, because the first example of how to call the function I gave here is just much more readable (it's important to write maintainable code!)

*On the notice:*
You say you don't see any errors/warnings if you pass `$_POST['example']` (you should quote the `'example'`, BTW, because that should issue a warning, too). Try changing your ini settings to:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT
#and
display_errors = 1
display_startup_errors = 1 # careful here!
```

Then, you'll see how many issues your code *really* has. [Check the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) to see what each setting does, how and when to use them.

Comment: i have `error_reporting( -1 );` but i don't see any error. (i forgot the quote only here, but in my script there are) thx to both!

Comment: @ipel: have you got an error handler set somewhere? and have you set `display_errors` to 1?

Comment: i have `error_reporting( -1 );` in phpinfo(); display_errors is ON, but in my hosting (godaddy) there is not an error log file, can i enable via php?

Comment: and sorry for this little off-topic question if my function is: `function myFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = null){ echo( 'something' ); }` should i add a return like this or nothing change? `function myFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = null){ echo( 'something' ); return; }`

Comment: You should set `error_log = true` (check the manual link @bottom of my answer), I don't now where the logs are on your host (`/var/log/apache2`?). On the return value [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350585/why-we-should-always-return-values-from-a-function/12351015#12351015), your function returns `null` implicitly, you needn't add an explicit return, if you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as:

```
function myfunction( $var1, $var2, $var3=null )
{
}
```

you can read more about function parameters [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) (see *Example#3*).

As for your second question (about notice) - you have to check your `$_POST` first:

```
if(isset($_POST['example']))
{
   myfunction($var1, $var2, $_POST['example']);
}
else
{
   myfunction($var1, $var2);
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
myfunction($var1, $var2, isset($_POST['example'])?$_POST['example']:null);
```

in that case you will hanlde your data correctly and error will be not shown due to that (and not due to errors suppressing).

Comment: It's not a copy-paste (since I was typing the same - but just a little bit later - just check that i have not `_` after `if`, for example). OP said that he does not see message, but correct way is no check - then the message will be not shown because of correct handling and not because errors suppressing.

Comment: He doesn't check the if the value `isset`, nor does he quote the key (which should produce a notice: unexptecte constant, assumed string). That, to me, means that the ini isn't set to strict, or display_errors was set to 0. (PS: sorry about the copy-paste accusation, it does look remarkably similar, though)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes, that's correct. Not sure I've got your point - but it's obvious - how to fix that, isn't it? (You and I provided correct samples in code for that).

Comment: My point is, the OP said: _" if $_POST[example] don't exist i see *no* error/notice"_, your answer doesn't explain why he _doesn't_ get a notice with the code he posted. My point is, he should set his `error_reporting`, and `display_errors` accordingly, to debug his code properly. Your code won't show errors, because there are no errors in it. His code _has_ got errors, but the OP doesn't see them.

Answer (score 1):

Equal to `NULL` or `false`

```
myfunction($var1, $var2, $_POST['example']);

function myfunction($var1, $var2, $example = false)
{
    if($example) {
       echo $example;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$example=false` is not same as it is not set (i.e. it is `null`)

Comment: If `$_POST[example]` is NULL so it is `FALSE`. `$_POST[example]` is exist, it's `TRUE`

Comment: thx. yes my function is already like this: `function( $var1, $var2, $var3=null )` but my question is if $_POST[example] is not set, is not an error to use it here: `myfunction( $var1, $var2, $_POST[example]);`

Comment: this still will produce notice, and, besides, if `$_POST['example']` exists (key is set), but value is `false` your sample will fail.

Comment: @ipel: check my answer on why you don't _see_ the notice (it's there, but you have to set your ini to show them)

Answer (score 0):

**First Case**

if your form has not submitted before, then the third argument will have the value `null` else the value submitted.

**Second case**

If your form has not submitted before then the third argument will have the value `false`, else `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.During the function definition declare the argument as an optional one.

```
class test{
public function myFun($arg1,$arg2,$arg3 = ''){
echo 'Argument 1 - '.$arg1;
echo 'Argument 2 - '.$arg2;
if($arg3!= '')
   echo 'Argument 3 - '.$arg3;
}
}
 $obj = new test();
 echo $obj->myFun('One','Two');
```